# Webpack Module Federation error "TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId] is not a function"

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I try to implement a simple example about Module Federation with vanilla js functions.

Directory structure:

```md
  ── packages
    ├── home
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── src
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   └── webpack.config.js
    └── nav
        ├── index.html
        ├── package.json
        ├── src
        │   ├── Header.js
        │   ├── index.js
        └── webpack.config.js
```

The expecting result is that `home` app render the `Header` of the `nav`.

Webpack config of `nav`

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "http://localhost:4001/",
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "nav",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            library: {type: 'var', name: 'nav'},
            exposes: {
                "./Header": "./src/Header"
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Module Federation Example',
        }),
    ],
}
```

Webpack config of `home`

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "http://localhost:4000/",
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "home",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            remotes: {
                nav: "nav@http://localhost:4001/remoteEntry.js"
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Module Federation Example',
        }),
    ],
}
```

This is the Header:

```js
export default () => {
    const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = 'Header';
    node.style = 'padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box;display: flex;background: aquamarine;font-family:sans-serif;'
    return node;
}
```

In `index.js` file in `home` is where i import the `Header`:

```js
import Header from 'nav/Header';

const Greetings = () => {
    const node = document.createElement('h1');
    node.innerHTML = 'App Shell';
    return node;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.appendChild(Greetings());
    document.body.appendChild(Header());
});
```

After build and serve on the url of the `home` app i retrieve this error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId] is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:66:41)
    at eval (index.js:2:68)
    at ./src/index.js (main.js:19:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:66:41)
    at main.js:217:37
    at main.js:219:12
```

You can reproduce here in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/Alessandroinfo/module-federation-example?file=README.md).

I tried to add a library option `library: {type: 'var', name: 'nav'},` in the **ModuleFederationPlugin** but i don't understand why is not working.

I expected to see the `nav/Header` rendered inside home app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The error arises because I was importing the remote module directly into the `index.js`.
The remote module is loaded asynchronously so it was not yet available for import and hence the error.

The fastest solution is to import the remote modules into a `bootstrap.js` file to make sure they are available and import it in `index.js`

**index.js**

```js
    import("./bootstrap");
```

**bootstrap.js**

```js
    import Header from 'nav/Header';
    // other logics ...
```